# How can I use ParameterExpression to parameterize an expression tree?

Tags: c#, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, expression-trees, cocor

I am learning to use expression trees/expressions in C#. I have gradually built up a parser, with which I can take a string in "calculator" syntax (like "2 * 3 + 14 * 4 / 7 - 5 * 5") and build and evaluate an abstract syntax tree (AST). It even calculates the correct answer! :-)  The AST consists of `Expression` nodes: arithmethical binary nodes (Add, Subtract, Multiply, Divide) and unary Constant nodes representing the integer values.

Next step: I want to add parameters to the expression to be parsed, like "2 * 3 + myVar1 * 4 / 7 - 5 * myVar2", and supply the actual values for the parameters at runtime (after the AST has been compiled). I can easily add the ParameterExpressions to the tree - but I cannot find out how to correctly compile my tree and supply the values.

The parser is built using Coco/R and an attributed Bachus-Naur grammar, and looks like this:

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using Ex = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression;
using System;

namespace AtgKalk
{
    public class Parser
    {
        public const int _EOF = 0;
        public const int _identifikator = 1;
        public const int _tall = 2;
        public const int _pluss = 3;
        public const int _minus = 4;
        public const int _ganger = 5;
        public const int _deler = 6;
        public const int maxT = 7;

        const bool T = true;
        const bool x = false;
        const int minErrDist = 2;

        public Scanner scanner;
        public Errors errors;

        public Token t;    // last recognized token
        public Token la;   // lookahead token
        int errDist = minErrDist;

        public Parser(Scanner scanner)
        {
            this.scanner = scanner;
            errors = new Errors();
        }

        void SynErr(int n)
        {
            if (errDist >= minErrDist) errors.SynErr(la.line, la.col, n);
            errDist = 0;
        }

        void Get()
        {
            for (; ; )
            {
                t = la;
                la = scanner.Scan();
                if (la.kind <= maxT) { ++errDist; break; }

                la = t;
            }
        }

        void Expect(int n)
        {
            if (la.kind == n) Get(); else { SynErr(n); }
        }

        void Calculator()
        {
            Ex n;
            CalcExpr(out n);
            Console.Write($"AST: {n} = ");
            Console.WriteLine(Ex.Lambda<Func<int>>(n).Compile()());
            // The above works fine as long as there are no parameter names in the input string
        }

        void CalcExpr(out Ex n1)
        {
            Ex n2; Func<Ex, Ex, Ex> f;
            Term(out n1);
            while (la.kind == 3 || la.kind == 4)
            {
                AddOp(out f);
                Term(out n2);
                n1 = f(n1, n2);
            }
        }

        void Term(out Ex n1)
        {
            n1 = null; Ex n2; Func<Ex, Ex, Ex> f = null;
            Fact(out n1);
            while (la.kind == 5 || la.kind == 6)
            {
                MulOp(out f);
                Fact(out n2);
                n1 = f(n1, n2);
            }
        }

        void AddOp(out Func<Ex, Ex, Ex> f)
        {
            f = null;
            if (la.kind == 3)
            {
                Get();
                f = (l, r) => Ex.Add(l, r);
            }
            else if (la.kind == 4)
            {
                Get();
                f = (l, r) => Ex.Subtract(l, r);
            }
            else SynErr(8);
        }

        void Fact(out Ex n)
        {
            n = null;
            if (la.kind == 2)
            {
                Number(out n);
            }
            else if (la.kind == 1)
            {
                Parameter(out n);
            }
            else SynErr(9);
        }

        void MulOp(out Func<Ex, Ex, Ex> f)
        {
            f = null;
            if (la.kind == 5)
            {
                Get();
                f = (l, r) => Ex.Multiply(l, r);
            }
            else if (la.kind == 6)
            {
                Get();
                f = (l, r) => Ex.Divide(l, r);
            }
            else SynErr(10);
        }

        void Number(out Ex n)
        {
            Expect(2);
            n = Ex.Constant(int.Parse(t.val), typeof(int));
        }

        void Parameter(out Ex n)
        {
            Expect(1);
            n = Ex.Parameter(typeof(int), t.val);
        }

        public void Parse()
        {
            la = new Token();
            la.val = "";
            Get();
            Calculator();
            Expect(0);
        }

        static readonly bool[,] set = {
        {T,x,x,x, x,x,x,x, x}

    };
    } // end Parser


    public class Errors
    {
        public int count = 0;                                    // number of errors detected
        public System.IO.TextWriter errorStream = Console.Out;   // error messages go to this stream
        public string errMsgFormat = "-- line {0} col {1}: {2}"; // 0=line, 1=column, 2=text

        public virtual void SynErr(int line, int col, int n)
        {
            string s;
            switch (n)
            {
                case 0: s = "EOF expected"; break;
                case 1: s = "identifikator expected"; break;
                case 2: s = "tall expected"; break;
                case 3: s = "pluss expected"; break;
                case 4: s = "minus expected"; break;
                case 5: s = "ganger expected"; break;
                case 6: s = "deler expected"; break;
                case 7: s = "??? expected"; break;
                case 8: s = "invalid AddOp"; break;
                case 9: s = "invalid Fakt"; break;
                case 10: s = "invalid MulOp"; break;

                default: s = "error " + n; break;
            }
            errorStream.WriteLine(errMsgFormat, line, col, s);
            count++;
        }
    } // Errors

    public class FatalError : Exception
    {
        public FatalError(string m) : base(m) { }
    }
}
```

My problem lies in line 63, I think:

```
    Console.WriteLine(Ex.Lambda<Func<int>>(n).Compile()());
```

Invocation:

```
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(args[0]); // if args[0] contains the input string :-)
                Parser parser = new Parser(scanner);
                parser.Parse();
```

Comment: You need a lambda where the parameters are passed it. You're creating a lambda that just returns an `int`

Comment: Ok - but how would you create a lambda that accepts an arbitrary number of parameters? –

Comment: You need to use something like `var expr2 = Ex.Lambda(expr, all_p.ToArray())`, where `expr` is synthesized, and all_p a `List<ParameterExpression>`. First, create the `all_p` list, and traverse the entire lambda body to collect the ParameterExpression you created in the `Parameter()` method. Or, in the `Parameter()` method, just add it to a global list there. You have to create the lambda with all the parameters. Then, you can say `int res = expr2.Compile().DynamicInvoke(1,2,..........)`. But, I would just pass a Dictionary<string,int> and dispense with collecting all parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I have now solved my problem. Thanks to [kaby76](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4779853/kaby76) for valuable tips leading me in the right direction. The example now can handle an arbitrary number of parameters (probably max 16, since this is the maximum number of input arguments for `Func<...>`)

The solution to the problem war threefold:

1. Collect the parameters and supply this collection of parameters to the `Lambda`
2. Remove the explicit type arguments from the `Lambda`, letting it infer types
3. Use DynamicInvoke to execute the resulting `Delegate`

The problematic statement then looks like this, for an expression with two parameters:

```
Console.WriteLine(Ex.Lambda(n, para).Compile().DynamicInvoke(3, 4));
```